# Can I use jsforce to launch/invoke a lightning flow

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, jsforce

I have an auto launch flow that I'd like to act as an API endpoint. The flow receives a few variables and creates tasks and cases.

I've used jsforce to call an apex rest API like it's [explained here](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#apex-rest:%7E:text=Run-,Apex%20REST,-If%20you%20have).

Here's my code example of using jsforce to call an apex endpoint:

```
const salesforce = config.getProperty('NewSalesforceRest');
const conn = new sf.Connection({ loginUrl: salesforce.host });

try {
  await conn.login(salesforce.userName, salesforce.Password + salesforce.Token);
} catch (error) {
  return res.status(500).send(errorResponse.ServerError(`Salesforce Apex login failure: ${error}`));
}

const apexPostResult = await conn.apex.post('/contact_us', req.body);
```

Is it possible to use jsforce to launch the flow? and if yes, could you please direct me to documentation or example on how to do it? or just post a sample as an answer?

Comment: a down vote without any explanation doesn't help. please let me know what's wrong with my question and allow me to make it a better question. what you've done doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Bhaman Not that I downvoted this but better off if you show some code of what you tried and where you stuck.

Comment: Thanks, @MohithShrivastava I've added more details and code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [send an arbitrary request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291193/2984) to Salesforce, and it so happens that you can [call a Flow directly](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_system_rest.htm&type=5).

First, build the request as:

```
var _request = {
  url: '/services/data/v54.0/actions/custom/flow/FlowName',
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(
    {
      inputs: [
        param1: value1,
        param2: value2,
      ]
    }
  ),
  headers : {
          "Content-Type" : "application/json"
      }
};
```

Which you then send after logging in and resetting the login url:

```
conn.request(_request, function(err, resp) {
     console.log(resp);
});
```

Be sure to visit the first link and provide an upvote there, too. I'm just putting it all together for you.

Comment: yes sir, I've upvoted the linked answer as well. I can't appreciate your help enough. Thanks so much!

Comment: I wish that help doc also had a link to the dev docs on invoking actions (like Flows in this case). The details are a bit spread across REST docs and Actions docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_flow.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_actions_invocable.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another option: use jsforce to execute anonymous Apex which calls your flow, like this:

```js
const apexCode = `Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.MyFlowApiName(
    new Map<String, Object>{
        'stringParam' => '${myString}',
        'numberParam' => ${myNumber}
    }
);`
await conn.tooling.executeAnonymous(apexCode);
```

See [this other thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161189) for more about invoking an auto-launched Flow from Apex.